# C++ transform issue

Tags: c++, transform

I need to read in from a csv file and store in a integer array, after read in the line and split the line with `boost::split`, I got a vector of string LineItems. I can convert it to integer array by:

```
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
   WorkArr[i]=stoi(LineItems[i]);
}
```

(I know the size and format of the csv therefore I can use an array to store.)
However, I would like to use transform to perform this task:

```
transform(LineItems.begin(),LineItems.end(),WorkArr,stoi);
```

But compiler said that it doesn't know which overloaded version of `stoi` to use (I am using VC++).

I know I can workaround in this way:

```
int MyStoI(string & ss) return stoi(ss);
transform(LineItems.begin(),LineItems.end(),WorkArr,MyStoI);
```

But this introduces another function `MyStoI`. Is there any method to perform this without introducing a new function?

Regds

LAM Chi-fung

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: error C2672: 'transform': no matching overloaded function found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using lambda? like this :

```
std::transform(LineItems.begin(), LineItems.end(),
    std::back_inserter(WorkArr),
    [](const std::string& str)
{
    return std::stoi(str);
});
```

if `WorkArr` is a normal array (not a vector) you can use it like this:

```
std::transform(LineItems.begin(), LineItems.end(), WorkArr,
    [](const std::string& str)
{
    return std::stoi(str);
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. lambda is too new to me, like an alien language ^_^